# 'NetworkClient Send with no connection' error when trying to send message from client to server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to send a custom network message from my client to my server and I'm getting an error from my SendTexture() function on the line `client.Send(AnimalDataMsgType.animalData, animalData);`

`NetworkClient Send with no connection UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkClient:Send(Int16, MessageBase) Client:SendTexture(Texture2D, String, String, Int32, Int32) (at Assets/Scripts/Client.cs:158) Client:SendOnButtonPress() (at Assets/Scripts/Client.cs:141) UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()`

I'm just getting into learning aspects of networking in unity so I don't know where I'm going wrong here. I've got everything going with initializing NetworkTransport and my client is connecting to my server so I'm confused why I'm getting a no connection error. I would really appreciate anyone that might help me solve this. Client and server side scripts attached below. Thank you!

**Client**

```
public class Client : NetworkBehaviour {

    NetworkClient client = new NetworkClient();

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;

    private string serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    private int port = 5708;
    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;
    private int reliableChannel;
    private int reliableSeqChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int unreliableSeqChannel;

    private string playerName;
    private int connectionId;
    private float connectionTime;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private bool isConnected = false;
    private byte error;

    private GameObject infoDisplayText;

    public Texture2D texToSend;
    string typeToSend = "Deer";
    string idToSend = "1";
    int strengthToSend = 80;
    int hitPointsToSend = 2;

    private void Start()
    {
        infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);

        // Run client/server on different machines
        //hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);  

        connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, serverIP, port, 0, out error);

        infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += playerName + " connected.\n";

        connectionTime = Time.time;
        isConnected = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isConnected)
            return;

        int recHostId, connectionId, channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected");
                infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Connected to Server.\n";
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SendOnButtonPress()
    {
        SendTexture(texToSend, typeToSend, idToSend, strengthToSend, hitPointsToSend);
    }

    public void SendTexture(Texture2D tex, string type, string id, int strength, int hitpoints)
    {
        AnimalData animalData = new AnimalData();

        animalData.Tex = tex.GetRawTextureData();
        animalData.Type = type;
        animalData.Id = id;
        animalData.Strength = strength;
        animalData.Hitpoints = hitpoints;

        client.Connect(serverIP, port);
        client.Send(AnimalDataMsgType.animalData, animalData);
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
public class Server : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;
    private int port = 5708;
    private int hostId;
    private int webHostId;
    private int reliableChannel;
    private int reliableSeqChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int unreliableSeqChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private GameObject infoDisplayText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);

        if (NetworkTransport.IsStarted)
        {
            isStarted = true;
            Debug.Log("NetworkTransport is Started.");
            infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "NetworkTransport is Started.\n";
        }

        Debug.Log("Server Started.");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Server Started.\n";

        setupRegisterHandler();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        int recHostId, connectionId, channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;

        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + " has connected");
                infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Player " + connectionId + " has connected\n";
                break;
        }
    }

    // Create a client and connect to the server port
    public void setupRegisterHandler()
    {
        NetworkServer.Listen(port);
        Debug.Log("Registering server callbacks");
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(AnimalDataMsgType.animalData, OnTextureReceive);
    }

    //Called when texture is received
    public void OnTextureReceive(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        AnimalData animalData = netMsg.ReadMessage<AnimalData>();

        string type = animalData.Type;
        Debug.Log("Type : " + type);

        string id = animalData.Id;
        Debug.Log("ID : " + id);

        int strength = animalData.Strength;
        Debug.Log("Strength : " + strength);

        int hitpoints = animalData.Hitpoints;
        Debug.Log("Hit Points : " + hitpoints);

        //Your Received Texture2D
        Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(1280, 1024);
        receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(animalData.Tex);
        receivedtexture.Apply();

        Debug.Log(type + " data received!");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += type + " data received!\n";
    }
}
```

**Player class**

```
public class Player : MessageBase
{
    public GameObject Avatar;

    public byte[] Tex;      // data coming from CanvasController
    public string Type;     // data coming from CanvasController
    public string Id;       // data coming from GameManager
    public int Strength;    // data coming from PlayerController
    public int Hitpoints;   // data coming from PlayerController
    public bool IsAlive;    // data coming from PlayerController
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling these two lines simultaneously:

```
client.Connect(serverIP, port);
client.Send(AnimalDataMsgType.animalData, animalData);
```

Generally, **Connect** function takes some time to establish the connection. So, when you are calling the **Send** function just after the **Connect** function, the connection is not yet established.
So, you can follow this approach:
 1. You call the connect function first.
 2. When connection is successful it calls a callback method **OnConnected**.
 3. you make a bool true inside **OnConnected**, like isConnected = true;
 4. Before calling send you check if isConnected is true;
More details here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkClient.Connect.html

Comment: That makes sense, but I have one other question because I think I'm still unclear on what constitutes a Connection and how long that connection persists. I am connecting to the server from my Connect() function so shouldn't I already be connected to begin with? Is the reason I am connecting again in my SendTexture() function is because I'm doing it from another instance of client?

Comment: Yes, because it'll try to connect again even if it is already connected and that may also throw error.

Comment: Could I ask one more thing? Would you possibly be able to provide a working example of what I'm trying to do so that I can understand this better? I feel like I'm just going in circles.

Comment: Would it be best if I called `client.Connect(serverIP, port);` in a coroutine? Then in `OnConnected()` I could set my send bool to true?

Comment: You don't need to Connect function in a coroutine. Call it in Start(). Inside, OnConnected you make your send bool true.
Only after that you should send your data.

Comment: When I move the Connect function to Start I get this error: `UNet Client Disconnect Error: CRCMismatch
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()` How should I then resolve this? Do I need to change something on the Server side?

Comment: That's another error. However, the point is, you can call the connect function wherever you want, on a button click or whatever before sending a message. But you have to make sure that the client has successfully connected. Calling Connect() doesn't mean you are connected and you can't make isConnected = true just after calling Connect(). You can make isConnected = true inside OnConnected() callback. I have already given you the link. Here it is again: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkClient.Connect.html

Comment: Also, unity's network classes are opensource. If you are interested to do it from low level, I would suggest going through this: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/networking/src.
Otherwise, you can always follow the easier way using this:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking

Comment: Thanks. I've gone through that Multiplayer tutorial about 12 times. It doesn't address anything regarding custom messages and I've not been able to apply the examples given in the tutorial to the things I'm trying to achieve because frankly, I'm just not very good at coding. And because of that, I'm having trouble connecting the dots and I just need someone to help me by showing me. Perhaps this is a good case for creating a Bounty?

Comment: I think so, because me myself is noob in unity networking. More experts would be interested if you set a bounty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157164/discussion-between-zayedupal-and-greybow).